# gradually appeared

Tags: word-meaning

> And then, the system notifications **gradually appeared**.

I want to know, "gradually appeared" means "Transparency decreasing" or "like typing, word after word appearing".

Comment: Please remember to include a source and describe the context. Otherwise, you may (did) attract close votes. See [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187) and the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) for tips and examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With just such context, one can't choose between your options.
Your phrase got nothing to do with a technical specification on how the notifications must appear.

According to the Oxford Dictionary

[**gradually**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gradually)

> In a gradual way; slowly; by degrees.

I think that the most common interpretation is that the notifications appeared **in a gradual way**, meaning that **all of them didn't appear instantly at the same time**. The first notification took its time to appear - modifying its transparency or word by word, that information is not present -  and then it was followed by a second notification spaced from the previous one by a period of time. But this is just a guess, an interpretation. In the absence of more context, you're free to imagine the scene.